# Joining .csv with shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, attribute-joins

I'm trying to join a .csv file with a shapefile in ArcGIS. In both the files theres a column named BlockID that are going to be joined the joined attribute between the two files. My problem is that when I do the join validaton it gets stuck at "counting the number of matchingrecords for the join" and after a while it says that the join is cancelled. I have done joins before, big ones like the one I'm doing this time, and never had this problem.

Does anyone know what might be the reason why the validation just cancels?

Comment: Yes, totally forgot to mention that. I will edit the post.

Comment: Try importing the csv to a file geodatabase and then join

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in ArcGIS, try this:

1. Create a new file geodatabase
2. Import your shapefile into the .gdb
3. Import your csv into the .gdb (ensure the data types for your fields match those of the imported shapefile that is now a feature in a geodatabase while you're working with the import settings, use the field map window)
4. Trying joining again

Sometimes csv's and shapefiles get a bit unpredictable in ArcGIS. Since a geodatabase is a proprietary database, anything within a geodatabase tends to operate more smoothly in ArcGIS. Once you do all your processing, you can always export your results out of the geodatabase.

Comment: RE: "Since a geodatabase is... proprietary" Whether or not a geodatabase is _proprietary_ has no bearing on the issue. What matters is that there is _consistency_ between assumptions about the data and the procedures applied to said data.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend using table to table on the CSV, or saving the CSV as excel and using Excel to Table to create a geodatabase table for use in joining. Joining csv's is really a pain and should be avoided.

Table to Table:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm

Excel to Table:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/excel-to-table.htm

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to change the .csv to .xls (not .xlsx) file and then add it as data. Join them by right click on the shapefile. Select the same data column from both datasets. It will join both the data, and you can visualize the data using existing shapefile.